# Construct a label based on IDs in the same table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

```
id  label   origin
1   G       Sales
2   K       Sales
3   G       Sales
4   K       Sales
1   K       Invoice
2   G       Invoice
3   K       Invoice
4   G       Invoice
5   G       Invoice
6   K       Invoice
1   K       Facts
2   G       Facts
3   G       Facts
4   K       Facts
6   G       Facts
7   G       Facts
```

Basically, I want to give all the IDs in different rows the same label based on a hierarchy. The hierarchy is Sales > Invoice > Facts.

So, I'd like to have the following table as a result

```
id  label   origin
1   G       Sales
2   K       Sales
3   G       Sales
4   K       Sales
1   G       Sales
2   K       Sales
3   G       Sales
4   K       Sales
5   G       Invoice
6   K       Invoice
1   G       Sales
2   K       Sales
3   G       Sales
4   K       Sales
6   K       Invoice
7   G       Facts
```

Please note, in the actual table I have millions of rows with lots of different IDs. Using a CASE WHEN statement is not feasible. Is there a way to do this efficiently in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this first by finding the label that corresponds to each id, and then using it on a join.

Note that I'm using the fact that your hierarchy is in alphabetical order - otherwise we would need another layer of mapping:

```sql
with data as (
select index i, split(value, ' ') x, x[0]::integer id, x[3] label, x[10] origin
from table(split_to_table((
$$1   G       Sales
2   K       Sales
3   G       Sales
4   K       Sales
1   K       Invoice
2   G       Invoice
3   K       Invoice
4   G       Invoice
5   G       Invoice
6   K       Invoice
1   K       Facts
2   G       Facts
3   G       Facts
4   K       Facts
6   G       Facts
7   G       Facts$$), '\n')
)), choose_hierarchy as (
    select id, array_agg([label, origin]) within group (order by origin desc) labels
    from data
    group by id
)


select data.id, labels[0][0]::string label, labels[0][1]::string origin
from data
join choose_hierarchy
on data.id=choose_hierarchy.id
order by i
```

[image]